# Set a theme on a specific QT application in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, gnome, themes, gtk, qt

How can I set a specific theme for a specific QT application? Globally I used a dark theme but for some applications I want to use the default theme of Ubuntu 16.04 (Ambiance). This is for a specific QT application.

I tried these commands inside my spreadsheet.desktop

```
Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/bin/et
```

or

```
Exec=env GTK2_RC_FILES=$HOME/.themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /usr/bin/et
```

or

```
Exec=env GTK_THEME=Ambiance:Default /usr/bin/et
```

But none worked.

Comment: __To  the reviewers__, The linked question is about a GTK application where this asks for a QT app. Two are different

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do so using `QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE` environment variable.

The syntax is like this

```
QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE=Breeze konsole
```

Here you're using `Breeze` theme for konsole application. GTK theme names should also work. I've tested this under KDE with `adwaita` (gtk theme) and `Breeze` (KDE theme) names. My original environment theme was set to Oxygen.

Note that, though it will override the styles of the controls, the Window decoration (which draws the titlebar and close,minimize buttons) won't change.

Comment: This did not work for me on KDE Plasma (5.10.2)

Comment: @jat255 Because the answer wasn't for Plasma 5.10.2. No needed to downvote an answer that wasn't asking solution for your specific plasma version! And you know what? This actually works in 5.10.1